# Google Analytics APIs: get two specific numbers only (as simple as possible)

Tags: api, google-analytics

I want to get two statistics (Visits today, visits total) from my GoogleAnalytics account.

I checked Google Analytics resources such as

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

But it seems pretty time-consuming to get a certain ID, oAuth and everything working. 
I do not need any user authentication, just an API request from my backend (GA authentication should be provided via request url for example).

To be honest, I found myself jumping from one link to another when doing tutorial and did not accomplish anything at the end.

What is the quickest way to get everything working? If there is a nice tutorial on getting JUST basic (two numbers) stuff from GoogleAnalytics I would be very grateful (everything I see is working almost as GA itself - just with custom styles/graphs etc. I need plain and simple number returned via REST api for instance.)

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auth is understandably complicated, but it sounds like you need [service account authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount) since you are querying your own data and need it to run on the back end.

The quickest way to get from zero to querying the API is to follow the [Hello Analytics Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php). I have linked you to the PHP service account page. But there are examples of service accounts, web apps, and installed apps in four different languages.

But an outline of the main steps are

1. Create a project in the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)
2. Within that project create a service account and download the p12 file.
3. add that service account email to the particular view you wish to query.
4. You are now ready to modify the Hello Analytics example.

Below is a simple query for the number [sessions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_sessions) today:

```
function getResults(&$analytics) {
  return $analytics->data_ga->get(
     'ga:XXXX', // Replace with your view ID.
     'today',
     'today',
     'ga:sessions');
  }
```

Feel free to ask any clarifying questions in the comments section.